# How to prevent specific pages from being moved/deleted within Structure?

Tags: ee2, structure, users

I am using the Structure plugin and would like to prevent certain pages from being moved/deleted by certain user groups.

Is there a way to define this with either structure or ExpressionEngine itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the Structure module and click 'Module Settings' at top right, you can set permissions based on member group - it will allow you to set permissions for moving or deleting pages, but it's across board rather than allowing you to choose which pages specifically.

Comment: It would be nice if there was an option "Only Content by User"

Comment: It certainly would. Why don't you pop it on their support forum as a feature request, they're usually very keen to improve the product.